# Make android device acting as a gcm servers

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

One instance of an application should communicate with the another instance on different device.
I'd like to NOT to have my own backend server.

I'd like to turn the android device into server in order to send the message to another device. I'd like to use topics.

Are there any limits (quotas per application) of:

1. number of such servers at a given point of time
2. number of topics
3. number of active client devices connected to the gcm

The GCM is designed to have 1 backend server.
What kind of strange behavior may I observe having plenty devices acting as a server. Using the same key

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on the number of servers (as long as you send via HTTP) or devices.

However, the problem in this approach is that you'll need to put your project's API key to the client app so it will be easy for adversary to find it out by decompiling the binary. Using your API key, they will be able to spam your users. It's a huge security hole.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that someone would be able to start spamming. The spamming device may flood the network. Will GCM block this paricular device or all devices using the same key?

Comment: @LulLul From GCM's perspective, it's not user devices but your server that sends messages (this is how it's supposed to be). So no, GCM won't stop it from spamming.